# react-native-router-flux: There is no route defined for key undefined. Must be one of 'home','activeJobs','favorites','inbox','profile'

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I currently have a production react-native app and I had **15** crashes yesterday referencing this error. So I am quiet desperate for an answer since I **CANNOT** reproduce this error in my dev environment nor in my own android phone.

The error is coming from `react-native-router-flux`

Here are the dependencies:

```
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.57.8",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
```

And my **Router.js**

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
return (
<Router>
  <Scene key="root">
    <Scene
      initial
      hideNavBar
      key="spinner"
      headerMode="none"
      panHandlers={null}
      component={SpinnerComponent}
    />

    <Tabs
      lazy
      key="tabBar"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      tabBarPosition={'bottom'}
      tabBarComponent={NavigationComponent}
    >
      <Scene
        initial
        key="home"
        headerMode="none"
        component={HomeComponent}
        panHandlers={null}
      />

      <Scene
        key="activeJobs"
        headerMode="none"
        component={ActiveJobsComponent}
        panHandlers={null}
      />

      <Scene
        key="favorites"
        headerMode="none"
        component={FavoritesComponent}
        panHandlers={null}
      />

      <Scene
        key="inbox"
        headerMode="none"
        component={InboxComponent}
        panHandlers={null}
      />

      <Scene
        key="profile"
        headerMode="none"
        component={ProfileComponent}
        panHandlers={null}
      />
    </Tabs>

    <Scene
      key="login"
      headerMode="none"
      component={LoginComponent}
      hideNavBar
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="displayOffer"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={DisplayOffersComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="selectJob"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={SelectJobComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="createJob"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={JobScheduleComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="define_title"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={DefineTitleComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="requirements"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={RequirementsComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="quantity_question"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={QuantityQuestionComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="add_comments"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={AddCommentsComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="multiple_choice"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={MultipleChoiceComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="user_description"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={JobDetailsComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="photos_and_direction"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={PhotosAndDirectionComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="price_or_offers"
      hideNavBar
      component={PriceOrOffersComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="googlePlaces"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={GooglePlacesComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="chat"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={ChatComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="publicProfile"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={PublicProfileComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="cardDetails"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={CardDetailsComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key='verifyPhone'
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={VerifyPhoneNumberComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key='payment'
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={PaymentComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key='emailAndPassword'
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={EmailAndPasswordComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key='confirmationAndReview'
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={ConfirmationAndReviewComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="extraOptions"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={ExtraOptionsComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="jobCreation"
      hideNavBar
      headerMode="none"
      component={JobCreationLogicContainer}
      panHandlers={null}
    />
  </Scene>
</Router>
);
};
```

I am jumping between tabs using: `Actions.jump('inbox');`

Any ideas why this would be happening? Maybe the way the Router is setup?

Comment: How do you jump back to the route with tabs? With pop() or key()?

Comment: @Mukeyii I do Actions.pop() if its just one scene that Im mounting on top of the current tab scene and Actions.reset('tabBar') when I have several scenes mounted.